# How key chain works for Bitgo multi-signature wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitgo

I am using bitgo service for Bitcoin wallet creation. Once I am creating bitcoin wallet using bitgo service, getting three different key chain which are user key chain, bitgo key chain, backup key chain which are storing in my database.

Suppose, hackers will get two key chain out of three, will they  make transaction or not?

Please assist me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone who has 2 out of the 3 private keychains (the private component of each keychain) can spend the Bitcoin. If you were hacked and the hacker was able to obtain 2 out of the 3, then they can spend your Bitcoin.